# ggplot pie chart with geom_col plots in anticlockwise order, violating the setting in coord_polar

Tags: r, ggplot2, pie-chart

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(2501)
sample_data <- data.frame(name=LETTERS[1:7], val=runif(7,0,1))

ggplot(sample_data) +
  geom_col(aes(x=1, y=val, fill=name), just = 0, width = 1) +
  geom_text(aes(x=1.5, y=val, label=name),
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  xlim(c(0, 2)) +
  coord_polar(theta = "y", start = 0, direction = 1) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(axis.text = element_blank(),
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_blank())
```

[image]

In the R code above, I generated a donut chart using `geom_col` with `coord_polar`. By setting `direction=1`, `coord_polar` should organizes the donut fractions in the clockwise order. However, as we can see in the generated plot, the order of the colored parts is reversed, while the labels plotted by `geom_text` are in the correct order. How can I fix this?

Comment: Try using `y = rev(val)` for `geom_text(mapping)` instead `y = val`.

Answer (score 0):

To position the labels in the correct order or in the same order as the slices of the pie you have to set the `group` aesthetic in `geom_text`. And to get your desired order for the slices or the stack you have to set `direction=-1`:

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(2501)
sample_data <- data.frame(name = LETTERS[1:7], val = runif(7, 0, 1))

ggplot(sample_data) +
  geom_col(aes(x = 1, y = val, fill = name), just = 0, width = 1) +
  geom_text(aes(x = 1.5, y = val, label = name, group = name),
    position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)
  ) +
  xlim(c(0, 2)) +
  coord_polar(theta = "y", start = 0, direction = -1) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(
    axis.text = element_blank(),
    legend.title = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    axis.line = element_blank()
  )
```

[image]